# ImportError: No module named PySide.QtCore

Tags: python, pyside

I have trouble using PySide in Eclipse.

I installed py26-pyside using macports and added `/opt/local/var/macports/software/py26-pyside/1.0.4_0/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PySide` to PYTHONPATH

But I got the above import error.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/opt/local/var/macports/software/py26-pyside/1.0.4_0/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages` to PYTHONPATH instead of what you have added.

Comment: problem fixed, thanks. Since PySide is the only folder in site-packages, why did the path I added not work?

Comment: Please accept my answer then to close the question (click the tick). With you path, it searched for `/opt/local/var/macports/software/py26-pyside/1.0.4_0/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PySide/PySide/…` rather than the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Running Linux, I had the same problem and I don't use PYTHONPATH. Simpler to put /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages in a file called /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/local.pth. It's pure python so it should work on other systems. The instructions in site.py are misleading.

Comment: What is this `local.pth` black magic? Is there docs for this?